# How to add and insert values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a php variables in mysql,but getting error while trying to add the php variables in a field and insert.
Here is my sql query:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (quantity,price) VALUES(quantity+$value,1000) WHERE id=$id;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want to update a row instead of inserting it?

Comment: What is the db error?

Comment: nope i've timestamps too that i can store each individual insertion.

Comment: So you don't want to update a row? You want to insert a new row then? Your question is rather unclear, we can't read your mind or see what your goal here is unless you explicitly tell us.

Comment: ok sorry if i was not clear enough in the question,
and yes i did not want to update the row. 
i want to insert each time.

Comment: for insert a new value, you cannot use where keywords, delete it and try again

Answer (score 1):

You can not insert rows with `WHERE` or by adding values (like you attempt with `quantity+$value`), as *there are no values* until after the insert has completed.

If you want to update an existing row,

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET quantity = quantity + $value,
    price = 1000
WHERE id = $id
```

Or if you want to insert a row,

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, quantity, price) 
VALUES ($id, $value, 1000)
```

Keep in mind that these queries are insecure, as they are not using prepared statements with placeholders.

Comment: thanks for your answer Qirel.
just want to know how can i insert new row for specific product id then?
my case is like whenever the customer buys a product i want to store the purchase record with timestamp.

Comment: Create a table with a primary key (probably some arbitrary ID), the customer ID (or any other unique customer-identifier), a timestamp (just use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default value) and the amount.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to update your query

```sql
UPDATE my_table 
  SET quantity = quantity + $value, price= 1000
  WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: i'm not and now i know i cant use the WHERE clause in an INSERT query,
i need to insert each time not update as i want to track the insertions based on timestamps later.
 thanks.

Comment: INSERT into mytable (logins) 
  SELECT max(logins) + 1 
  FROM mytable

Comment: you can use sub query similar to above query

Answer (score 0):

you cannot insert row using the "WHERE".

for insert you can use:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, quantity, price) VALUES ($id, $value, 1000);
```

for update you can use:

```
UPDATE my_table 
   SET quantity = quantity + $value,
       price = 1000
   WHERE id = $id;
```

for reference you can see:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp
```